# why isn't it endless loop of while?(c)

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
     unsigned long long f;
     int n;
     printf("factorial:");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     printf("%d! = ",n);
     f = n;
     while (--n)
         f*=n;
     printf("%llu\n",f);
     return 0;
 }
```

I thought it would work endless loop in while-loop.
However when I put negative number, it works.
--> factorial : -1
-1! : 0
Why this thing happened?
I wonder why zero was printed to the end.
Pleaseeeeee help me.

Comment: I sense signed overflow...

Comment: STEP THROUGH THE CODE IN THE DEBUGGER!  You'll see that the value becomes 0 ... and you'll see  "when", and  "why" :)  Don't "guess".  OBSERVE!  Your debugger is a great tool - USE IT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while condition will execute till the condition is false.  This means after the while loop `!n` which in C is the same as `n == 0`.  If you subtract `1` from `n = -1` sufficiently many times it will signed underflow and become positive and then eventually `0`. Hence it is not an infinite loop.

`f` is unsigned and you multiply it by a negative number which then is interpreted as very large number.  It turns out that with the input `-1` at `n == -67` `f` becomes `0` due to unsigned overflow:

```
n  f
-2 18446744073709551615
-3 2
-4 18446744073709551610
...
-65 9223372036854775808
-66 9223372036854775808
-67 0
...
2 0
1 0
```

Comment: This code isn't endless loop because of underflow. Also the value of f is 0 because of unsigned overflow. Am i understanding correctly? Thank you for your answer.